# Why should I compile Jade templates?

Tags: node.js, pug, cdn, bower

I have converted my existing Express application to use bower. Bower puts local copies of my dependencies on disk which I then reference in my jade templates.

When I deploy my app to production I would like to use a cdn to deliver these dependencies.

So I'm looking at grunt-google-cdn to replace my the references to the bower_components folder with addresses of the scripts on the cdn.

grunt-google-cdn seems to only work with html files. Does this mean I *should* be compiling my Jade views down to HTML?

I assume there is a small(?) performance gain because Express will have to compile/render the Jade view every time its requested.

What other advantages are there for compiling Jade views before deploying my app?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood. frontend or backend?

Comment: I was wondering if I was missing something. grunt-google-cdn only seems to work against HTML files, yet I'm not compiling my Jade down to HTML, I could - there isn't anything stopping me, but I would like to understand the pros and cons of doing so.

Frontend.

Answer (score 0):

If you precompile your templates to HTML you cannot pass variables, so its always a static template.

You can precompile you template as JavaScript, that's the client option, usually you use it to render the template on the client side. It also allows you to pass variables (locals).